# How to Change Application Icon through Code

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a project and want to change its main application icon (EXE Icon) occasionally like X-mas or whatever through code. Tried some ways but its not working and rest only works to change Form's icon.

[image]

Comment: I don't think it's possible because the icon is part of the resources that are compiled with the application

Comment: Not the exe icon, but probably not much reason why you couldn't re-create a desktop shortcut maybe

Comment: i will try that too mate but it will be better if can change EXE icon.